# LXDE some windows are longer than the screen's height

Tags: window, lxde

[image: like so]

I'm using LXDE on my notebook. The screen is so small that some windows are too long to fit in it. Since it's LXDE there's no bottom workspace where the rest of the window should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+click on the window and drag the window up. Should work in LXDE.

Comment: so it was that simple! thanks alot!!!! This was really bugging me for so long! :)

Comment: I used LXDE on a netbook for a few weeks getting grumpy at this. Stumbled on this accidentally! Glad it worked for you too. Can we whack a solved on this and get it out of "unanswered".

Comment: I get a message that I cannot accept the answer in ten minutes. Don't worry; you get your points ;)

Comment: :P Now I feel embarrassed! I spent half the day going through the unanswered section today trying to clear out old questions. Found half were actually answered. (Also points are tasty!)

Comment: yeah I noticed. most unanswered questions are asked by users with 1 reputation points or so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11988/discussion-between-mina-michael-and-julian-stirling)